# How to add multiple StaticBox(s) with child items within each StaticBox on a panel?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

With wxpython, I want to create multiple StaticBox(s) on a panel, add some widgets to each staticbox. How can I do that? A minimal example to start with:

```py
import wx

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, size=(700, 500))
panel = wx.Panel(frame)
vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

# Three StaticBox, with a StaticText within each
for n in range(3):
    sizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL, wx.StaticBox(panel,label=f"Box {n}"))
    sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(panel, label=f"StaticText of box {n}"))
    vbox.Add(sizer, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

panel.SetSizer(vbox)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

What's wrong with my code, because I got the following window:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.StaticBoxSizer.html gives a good example of how to use this widget container.

Here is your method modfied and a more pedantic method, commented out, using the old adage explict is better than implicit.

```
import wx

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, size=(700, 500))
panel = wx.Panel(frame)
vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

# Three StaticBox, with a StaticText within each
#sz1 = wx.StaticBoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL, panel, "Box1")
#sz1.Add(wx.StaticText(sz1.GetStaticBox(), wx.ID_ANY,"This window is a child of staticbox 1"))
#sz2 = wx.StaticBoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL, panel, "Box2")
#sz2.Add(wx.StaticText(sz2.GetStaticBox(), wx.ID_ANY,"This window is a child of staticbox 2"))
#sz3 = wx.StaticBoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL, panel, "Box3")
#sz3.Add(wx.StaticText(sz3.GetStaticBox(), wx.ID_ANY,"This window is a child of staticbox 3"))
#vbox.Add(sz1, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
#vbox.Add(sz2, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
#vbox.Add(sz3, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

for n in range(3):
    sizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL, panel,label=f"Box {n}")
    sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(sizer.GetStaticBox(), label=f"StaticText of box {n}"))
    vbox.Add(sizer, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

panel.SetSizer(vbox)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

It should be noted that some `themes` (on Linux, don't know about other platforms) don't display the box. So while it may work on your machine, it may not on others, depending on their chosen desktop appearance.

[image]